# Pymc3: how to defined an ordered vector of parameters

Tags: python, pymc3

I'm trying to do an ordered logistic regression, one parameter of which is an ordered vector of cutpoints. I'm not sure how I can define them.

One very stupid way I have come up with is to just define each component of the vector manually, using one as the other's bound:

```
with pm.Model() as bound_model:
    a = pm.Normal('a', mu=0, sd=10)
    BoundedB = pm.Bound(pm.Normal, upper=a)
    b = BoundedB('b', mu=0, sd=10)
    BoundedC = pm.Bound(pm.Normal, upper=b)
    c = BoundedC('c', mu=0, sd=10)

    bound_trace = pm.sample(1000)
```

This is hardly efficient and I'm not sure whether they will work as expected. Is there better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a missing feature in pymc3 I guess. I might write a pull request, but in the meantime you can use something like this:

```
class Ordered(pymc3.distributions.transforms.ElemwiseTransform):
    name = "ordered"

    def forward(self, x):
        out = tt.zeros(x.shape)
        out = tt.inc_subtensor(out[0], x[0])
        out = tt.inc_subtensor(out[1:], tt.log(x[1:] - x[:-1]))
        return out

    def backward(self, y):
        out = tt.zeros(y.shape)
        out = tt.inc_subtensor(out[0], y[0])
        out = tt.inc_subtensor(out[1:], tt.exp(y[1:]))
        return tt.cumsum(out)

    def jacobian_det(self, y):
        return tt.sum(y[1:])
```

And use it like this:

```
N = 10
with pm.Model() as model:
    pm.Normal('y', mu=np.zeros(N), sd=1, shape=N, 
              transform=Ordered(), testval=np.arange(N))
```

**Edit**: A *very* short explanation about what is happening here:

We define a map from $R^n$ to the set of ordered sequences by

```
f(x_1) = x_1,\quad f(x_i) = f(x_{i - 1}) + exp(x_i)
```

Since this is a nice bijective function, we can compute the probability density on $R^n$ by

```
P_{R^n}(x) = P_{ordered}(f(x)) \cdot |J_{f(x)}|
```

where J is the jacobian of the transformation.

The sampler will only see the unconstrained values. This is pretty much how `Bound` is implemented in the first place.

If you want more details, you can have a look at the [stan manual](https://github.com/stan-dev/stan/releases/download/v2.14.0/stan-reference-2.14.0.pdf). It contains a nice description of these transforms, and the math is the same for pymc3 and stan.

Comment: Thanks! I run a simple sampling and the order constraint seems to be meet, though I'm not really sure what's going on there. Don't even know there is a `transform` argument.. Looking forward to you PR!